# Need help in creating a view in sql with following data

Tags: sql, view, case

the table I am working on contains data in following format

```
Name | A | B | C
----------------
abc  | 1 | 0 | 1
xyz  | 0 | 1 | 1
pqr  | 0 | 0 | 1
```

I need to create a view a like this

```
Name | Type
abc  | A
abc  | C
xyz  | B
xyz  | C
pqr  | C
```

Will using case and when be helpful?
like

```
case when A=1 then 'A'
     when B=1 then 'B'
     when C=1 then 'C'
     else ''
     end as type
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per SO you should respond something to the question you have asked..if it helps you any of the answer ..do the upvote ..happy coding

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me! I can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Table :

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (Name varchar(3), A int, B int, C int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Name, A, B, C)
VALUES
    ('abc', 1, 0, 1),
    ('xyz', 0, 1, 1),
    ('pqr', 0, 0, 1)
;
```

Script

```
Select Name,[Type] from (
select Name,CASE WHEN VAL = 1 then COL ELSE NULL END Type,VAL from @Table1
CROSS APPLY(VALUES('A',A),('B',B),('C',C))CS(COL,VAL)
)T WHERE T.Type IS NOT  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`

```
select name,'A' from t where a = 1 union all
select name,'B' from t where b = 1 union all
select name,'C' from t where c = 1;
```

You can also group the where condition as:

```
select name, col
from
  (select name, 'A' col, a val from t union all
  select name, 'B', b from t union all
  select name, 'C', c from t)
where val = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use union all to select all the records from the table and insert into the view. The Below query would suffice your requirement. Thank you.

```
create or replace view test1 as (
select name,field from (
select name,'A' as field from test where a = 1 union all
select name,'B' as field from test where b = 1 union all
select name,'C' as field from test where c = 1));
```